# Why does 'a' prematurely end this loop?

Tags: c, cs50

Pointers rather than straight answers if you will please.

This loop does some manipulation on chars and outputs a ciphertext `c` based on a key `k` and some plaintext `p`.

When 'a' or 'A' comes up in the plaintext, the program will output that letter as expected but then end the loop prematurely.

`p` suddenly becomes just one character long, this character being 1.

```
while (i < strlen(p))
{
    char stdp = p[i];
    char stdk = k[j];

    if (isalpha(stdp))
    {
        if (islower(stdp))
        {
            p[i] = stdp - 'a';
            Aa = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            p[i] = stdp - 'A';
            Aa = 1;
        }

        if (islower(k[j]))
        {
            k[j] = stdk - 'a';
        }
        else
        {
            k[j] = stdk - 'A';
        }
    }

    if (isalpha(stdp))
    {
        c[i] = ((p[i] + k[j]) % 26);
    }
    else
    {
        c[i] = p[i];
    }

    if (isalpha(stdp))
    {
        if (Aa == 1)
        {
            c[i] = c[i] + 'A';
        }
        else if (Aa == 0)
        {
            c[i] = c[i] + 'a';
        }
    }

    if (isalpha(stdp))
    {
        if (j + 1 == kk)
        {
            j = (j + 1) % kk;
            strcpy(k, argv[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
        }
    }

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Here's the best pointer you will get: use a debugger to trace the execution of your program. If you still need help here please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `while (i < strlen(p))` is usually not a good idea; it converts linear algorithms into quadratic ones.  You keep testing `isalpha(stdp)` without changing `stdp` so the repeated test is unnecessary too.  You should probably pre-process the key so you don't ever need to modify that.  Are you sure your problem isn't that `A` gets mapped to `'\0'` and therefore you seem to terminate the encrypted string?

Comment: Because the value of a character in `p` can affect whether the loop ends, it's not a good idea to change any of its characters when possible.

Comment: Perhaps having more meaningful variable names would help

Comment: thanks @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved the issues I was facing with the program terminating early.

Most of the issues seem to have been solved by stopping the constant refs to `strlen(p)` and just assigning that to a static variable. I have tried to tidy up the code as suggested.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if (argc != 2 || argv[1] == NULL)//no more than 1 arg  and not empty
{
    printf("Command requires one argument to run.\n");
    return 1;
}

char *k = malloc(100);
strcpy(k, argv[1]);
int kInt = strlen(k);

for (int i = 0, n = kInt; i < n ; i++)// iterating though the key to check it is alphabetic
{
    if (isalpha(k[i]) == false)
    {
        printf("Make sure key is alphabetic!\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

printf ("plaintext: ");  

char *p = malloc(100);
strcpy(p, get_string());
int pInt = strlen(p);

int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int Aa = 0;

char *c = malloc(100);

while (j < kInt)
{
    if (islower(k[j]))
    {
        k[j] = k[j] - 'a';
    }
    else                
    {
        k[j] = k[j] - 'A';
    }
    j++;
}

j = 0;

while (i < pInt)
{
    if (isalpha(p[i]))
    {
        if (islower(p[i]))
        {
            p[i] = p[i] - 'a';
            Aa = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            p[i] = p[i] - 'A';
            Aa = 1;
        }

        c[i] = ((p[i] + k[j]) % 26);

        if (Aa == 1)
        {
            c[i] = c[i] + 'A';
        }
        else if (Aa == 0)
        {
            c[i] = c[i] + 'a';
        }

        if (j + 1 == kInt)
        {
            j = (j+1) % kInt;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
    else if (isalpha(p[i]) != true)
    {
        c[i] = p[i];
    }

    i++;
}

printf("ciphertext: %s\n", c);

free(c);
free(k);
free(p);
}
```